# What is the difference between (Lightning Data Service) force:recordData and lightning:recordEditForm when it comes to creating or updating a record?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am struggling to understand the need to have a force:recordData and a lightning:recordEditForm when both do almost similar things. Is one better than the other? I know lightning:recordEditForm supports lightning:inputField which could make life easier for some, but I am certain there are other differences. Care to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither one is necessarily "better" than the other; they're both tools to be used. The main difference between the two is that one is intended for *scripted* access to records (force:recordData), while the other is for *providing a UI* to edit a record (lightning:recordEditForm). Use the former if you just need lightweight access to a record, and the latter if you need to provide a user interface that resembles a standard record edit form.

Comment: The latter also provides an easy way to access what `apex:inputField` use to be. I sometimes find myself throwing away the actual save/submit methods because I just needed the SObject field bind (and subsequently manually finding the value via aura:id).

Comment: @tsalb That's a good point, but I consider that more of a workaround; they really need to have similar functionality on the force:recordData object or something else entirely.

Comment: maybe one day, they will let us use `lightning:inputField` standalone. wishful thinking.

Comment: lightning:recordEditForm internally uses Lightning Data Service for DML

Comment: @Praveen That makes sense, of course. Why invent something new when you have what you already need? That's the power of Lightning Components, making things reusable.